# git-bash.exe: how to run single command?

Tags: windows, git, bash, powershell

I am using the [portable version of Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.3-64-bit.7z.exe), but when I use `git-bash.exe` to run a single command, it looks like it does not work. Can you help me find out where is the problem?

I have a PowerShell script to call below command. But looks like it does not work. I am not able to let the new cmd window to pause to see the error log:

```
cmd /c "d:\git\git-bash.exe dos2unix d:\test\my-script.sh"
```

But If double click and run `bash-exe.sh`, then in the `git-bash.exe` window type

```
dos2unix d:\test\my-script.sh
```

then it works.

Comment: I don't know how git-bash.exe works, but try adding a -c: `cmd /c "d:\git\git-bash.exe -c dos2unix d:\test\my-script.sh"`

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not work"? What behavior do you expect, and how does that differ from the behavior you actually get?

Comment: Can you try running that same command from, say, a command prompt? Then you can see any errors that may result...

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to call EXEs from PowerShell. One of the best ways I've found that allows you the most control is the Start-Process cmdlet. Instead of calling a cmd.exe window try this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'd:\git\git-bash.exe' -ArgumentList 'dos2unix d:\test\my-script.sh'
```

Better yet convert that shell script into native PowerShell! :)

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I got a walkaround. In the portable git, under \usr\bin, there is a exe called dos2unix.exe, so that I can directly call dos2unix.exe from my powershell scripts, not from git-bash.exe then call dos2unix command.

```
 cmd /c "d:\git\usr\bin\dos2unix.exe d:\test\my-script.sh"
```

With this walkaround, the problem resolved. But I still don't know why powershell calls dos2unix to parse my file does not work (I mean the file is not converted after call that command).

Comment: This worked for me after I changed the path to the script file to Linux-style (`/d/test/my-script.sh`). With the Windows-style path I get dos2unix: Failed to open temporary output file: No such file or directory...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is use the `base.exe`, e.g:

```sh
"%ProgramFiles%\Git\bin\bash.exe" start.sh
```

Comment: This runs a script. The OP specified that he wants to run a command.